# Adding Images To UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

In the database I have a list of image paths, the paths look like this.

assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=94473FB8-A6CE-4775-9C57-B8350B335E2B&ext=JPG

I am trying to take that path and load an image with it. But graphImage is returning nil and the image path is not nil.

How can I load a image with the path into my cell's UIImageView?

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{


     NSString *imagePath  = [array_photos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
     UIImage  *graphImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];

     cell.photoImageView.image = graphImage;



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the paths you have are for the asset library (aka your iPhone's photo library), you need to load them in a different way. Use the `ALAssetsLibrary`'s

```
- (void)assetForURL:(NSURL *)assetURL resultBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock)resultBlock failureBlock:(ALAssetsLibraryAccessFailureBlock)failureBlock
```

Be sure to include `AssetsLibrary.framework` in your project.

Comment: Yes, looks like your right! The implementation is a different story. Thanks for the step forward then.